# Retrieving Transfer function from Block Diagram (Direct Form I or II)

Tags: transfer-function, dsp, block-diagram

I've done a few examples for the opposite of the asked question that is to make Direct Form I or II diagrams from the given Transfer Function H(Z). But when I try to backtrack and apply the same logic I end up getting a different answer.
Below is the example I'm trying to solve.
[image]

The adder with 2*X(Z)z^-1 is connected to the y(n) junction.

The answer I got was

Y(Z) = X(Z)[(5+3-{(1/3)*z^-1}+1+{(1/2)*z^-1} + 2z^1]

Comment: In the future, try to improve your question by providing more clarity: what is it you are doing and, if it's a homework (or even personal exercises), provide whatever you have been doing so far that got you stuck. Otherwise, people might think you're trying to coerce them into doing your job. It's probably the reason why you got downvoted. For example, you could have said: I need to determine the t.f. of this picture, this is what I have tried but, I got stuck at this point. Something along those lines.

Comment: Sorry will take care next time onwards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Divide et impera. There are three branches going to the output: the top one is a simple feedforward, the other two are direct form II and you can readily obtain their transfer functions (denominator terms are on the left, numerator on the right). Then simply add them and, from that, you can obtain the difference equation. Do you think you can take it from here?